# Copy vectors from constant variables

Tags: c++

I'm wrinting a function where I need to respect the following interface:

```
double logDensity(double x, PDFType type,
                  std::vector<std::vector<double const *> > const &parameters,
                  double const *lower, double const *upper) const;
```

I need to split that `parameters` vector into two vectors inside this function:

```
vector<double> f = (parameters[0]);
vector<double> t = (parameters[1]);
```

However this code leads me to these errors messages:

```
DPwexp.cc: In member function 'double pwexponential::DPwexp::logDensity(double, PDFType, const std::vector<std::vector<const double*> >&, const double*, const double*) const':
DPwexp.cc:38:38: error: conversion from 'const std::vector<const double*>' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<double>' requested
 vector<double> f = (parameters[0]);
                                  ^
```

What is the best way to copy those two vectors to new variables inside my function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If parameters are passed by `const&`, the intend was not to change them inside the function. Why you need to *copy* them? The prototype assumes that you'll work with the parameters' values without changing.

```
const vector<double const*>& f = (parameters[0]);
const vector<double const*>& t = (parameters[1]);
```

Comment: I can't properly use the values if I set them as constants. For instance, I can't iterate them and other values by them. Can I?

Comment: You can iterate by const_iterator, you cannot only change the values.
What is "...other values by them"?

Comment: `DPwexp.cc:47:24: error: invalid operands of types 'const double* const' and 'double' to binary 'operator*'
     ref[0] = f[0]*dif[0];`

Comment: You have a vector of pointers to double, so this should be `(*f[0]) * dif[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
// Create f with the right number of elements.
std::vector<double> f(parameters[0].size());

// Use std::transform to convert pointers to double and
// store them in f.
std::transform(parameters[0].begin(), parameters[0].end(), 
               f.begin(), [](double const* in) { return *in; });

// Similarly for t.
std::vector<double> t(parameters[1].size());
std::transform(parameters[1].begin(), parameters[1].end(), 
               t.begin(), [](double const* in) { return *in; });
```